# deluge-console: Username does not exist

Tags: linux, daemon, deluge

I've set up `deluged` as a service with systemd to run as user `deluge`. The daemon works, since I can use the web-ui and connect with `deluge-console` if I type in credentials manually. However, when I just run `deluge-console` (locally on the same machine) as my regular user -- i.e. not as `deluge` -- I just get the "Username does not exist" error message.

The daemon's home directory is `var/lib/deluge` and `var/lib/deluge/.config/deluge/auth` contains only `test:test:10`. The same goes for `~/.config/deluge/auth`. I've been made to understand that the latter file is what `deluge-console` will authenticate with by default when run as my user. Apparently it doesn't.

- Typing `connect localhost test test` inside `deluge-console` works.
- Running `deluge-console -c ~/.config/` or `deluge-console -c
  ~/.config/deluge` doesn't work (it isn't clear to me what the devs
  mean by "config folder location").
- Hidden away in http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Authentication they say
  that there should always be a "localclient" entry in `auth` -- adding
  that to both auth files does not help.

What am I missing?

Not a duplicate of: https://superuser.com/a/619383/36197

This is done on a Raspberry Pi 3 running OSMC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which of the things did it, but I could connect automatically with the console after running:

```
systemctl stop deluged
systemctl start deluged
```

It's not apparent to me when this needed to be done. I was under the impression that I could edit the auth file while the daemon was running and it would look it up every time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same OS and hardware.

Set the config parameter `-c` to point to your Deluge config directory where your deluge.pid, auth, core.conf, dht.state and other files live.

```
$ deluge-console -c /var/lib/deluge/.config/deluge/ "add '/home/osmc/Downloads/totally not weird.torrent'"
Attempting to add torrent: /home/osmc/Downloads/totally not weird.torrent
Torrent added!
```